# i got 302 code on ahrefs, but i dont have any redirect on my site

Tags: wordpress, redirect, dns, hosting, cloudflare

hello im using wordpress for making sites, but my site have 302 error code and i dont have any redirection stuff on my site which is shown at ahrefs. when the site opened its really normal

page inspect also showing 301, but when the site opened its really normal
, you can see the following error on here
[error 302](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05ZSH.png)

i hope anyone can help me on this issues because i think there's really impact on SEO

Thanks,

i've tried remove all links, use new cloudflare, make a new cloudpanel, and there's nothing wrong with my domain which buyed from namecheap. and the issues still occurs until now